# Contact form with MySQL sends Email when form is filled in

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Im trying to make a contact form on my private portfolio site. The link between the contact form and the database is made. But now I would like to receive a Mail notification when someone sends in a filled in form.

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get helpful answers, please include the code you have tried so far to solve this problem so we can help you debug or improve it. That's how SO works.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this:

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: janfitz answered the question, but a example code that i used is:
`<?php
$to = 'destination@server1.com';
$subject = 'Subject of email';
$body = 'Write here your message';
$headers = 'From: user@server2.com';
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
?>`

Comment: missing **header** "mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);"

Answer (score 0):

// Multiple recipients

```
$to = 'johny@example.com, sally@example.com'; // note the comma
```

// Subject

```
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';
```

// Message

```
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Johny</td><td>10th</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';
```

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set

```
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
```

// Additional headers

```
$headers[] = 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com';
$headers[] = 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com';
```

// Mail it

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

[link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)